# How to reduce the time taken by the glue etl job(spark) to actually start executing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I want to start a glue etl job, though the execution is fair (time concerns), however, the time taken by glue to actually start executing the job is too much.

I looked into various documentation and answers but none of them could give me the solution. There was some explanation of this behavior: cold start but no solution.

I expect to have the job up asap, it takes sometimes around 10 mins to start a job which gets executed in 2 mins.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's not possible now. Glue uses EMR under the hood and it requires some time to spin up a new cluster with desired number of executors. As far as I know they have a pool of spare EMR clusters with some most common DPU configurations so if you are lucky your job can get one and start immediately, otherwise it will wait.

Comment: >As far as I know they have a pool of spare EMR clusters with some most common DPU configurations so if you are lucky your job can get one and start immediately, otherwise it will wait.

I did not get this. Could you please elaborate on the following points:
- spare EMR clusters 
- most common DPU configs, what are these?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know details. Some time ago I was told by support guy that Glue has hot spare EMR clusters but he didn't mention their configs.